# C++ Override Destructor and ownership transfer of a member variable

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, unique-ptr, pointer-to-member

I am not very proficient in C++. So I'll explain my problem as clearly as possible and when you are answering,please do some explanation.

So my problem involves 2 classes(A and B) with another class in a framework which I don't have access to. A has a pointer to B and B has a pointer to the A (raw pointers). The following show the interactions between the 2 classes.

```cpp
class A {
  public:
    void method(){
      this->b_ = new B(this);
      SomeServiceClass::doSomething(std::unique_ptr<B>(this->b_));
    }

  private:
    B *b_;
}

class B {
  public:
    B(A *a){
      this->a_ = a;
    }
    someOtherMethod(){
    }

  private:
    A *a;
}
```

So what really happens is, A creates first, and inside a `method()` of A , I create B and pass the B as a `unique_ptr` to some other method implemented in another class of a framework(which I don't have access). So that way I transfer ownership of B to that other class. But during the lifetime of A, I want to access B's other methods. That is why I keep a raw pointer to B in the class A. (I could have used a `shared_ptr` instead but that `SomeServiceClass::doSomething` requires a `unique_ptr`). But my question is at the time A is destroyed. Should I override the destructor of A and assign `this->b_ = null` ? Or maybe delete ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `B::_a` __own__ the instance of `A` ?  If yes then delete it (in B's destructor). If no then don't. If don't know then we can't help you as this is a design issue.

Comment: Get rid of `B *b_;` in A.  Ask the SomeServiceClass to get the `B*` that you can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as the call to

```
SomeServiceClass::doSomething(std::unique_ptr<B>(this->b_));
```

ends, the destructor of the `unique_ptr` has destroyed what it points to, potentially<sup>*</sup> making `b_` a useless dangling pointer. Do not try to read `b_` anywhere else, which includes not deleting it in `A`'s destructor.

If a function takes a `unique_ptr` parameter, then that function is claiming ownership of the pointed-to object, and you are not allowed to try to access it after the function call. You should backtrack to your real goal and re-evaluate your approach.

(If a function takes a `unique_ptr&` parameter, that function is probably not written well. At the very least, you should not assume that the stored pointer after the call is the same as it was before the call.)

---

<sup>*</sup> *The alternative to `b_` being dangling involves `SomeServiceClass` calling `unique_ptr::release()` at some point. In either case, the original pointer is no longer yours to access.*

Comment: Good point. The framework could store the `B` indefinitely or destroy it immediately and there's no way to know (other than reading the framework's documentation). Keeping and using a reference to the `B` could easily be a fatal mistake.